# Is Possible Magento Allows Change Shipping Cost calculate by Individual Product Weight instead of Package Weight?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

When I try to calculate shipping price, it `calculated by overall package weight`, I need `shipping cost calculated by individual products weight`,**I need like if two products in the cart the shipping price should be calculated by individually now the shipping price calculated by overall package weight**.

explanation: 
Product Details:

Product A: weight 100kg - shipping cost 100
Products B: weight 10kg - shipping cost 10

**Shipping Cost Details:**

100kg : 100
10kg : 10
110kg : 90

*Here my cart weight 110kg, the cost obviously 90. I need the shipping price calculated by individual product weight, `what I expected is the shipping cost 10 + 100 = 110.`

Is possible?

Note : Using [Matrix Rate](http://webshopapps.com/row/magento-1-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html)